# Xamarin Google Places Location

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, google-places-autocomplete

I was using below code in Xamarion.Android,

```
GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity)
      .AddApi(PlacesClass.GEO_DATA_API)
      .Build();
       Client.Connect();

AutocompletePredictionBuffer buffer = await PlacesClass.GeoDataApi
            .GetAutocompletePredictionsAsync(client, query, bounds, null);
```

Buffer use to get the required details. After deprecation of Android.Gms.Location.Places. I enable the Places API from the console and started using the new package Google.Places.

```
AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.NewInstance();
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);   
var request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.InvokeBuilder().SetLocationBias(bounds1).SetCountry("US").SetSessionToken(token).SetQuery(query).Build();

var prediction = placesClient.FindAutocompletePredictions(request);
var resp = prediction.Result;
```

Application breaks on prediction.Result.  Due to no result. What i am missing?

Comment: Did you install the package  from https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents?  It is a binding library for for the Google Play Services Client Library . So you would better post your problem at https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260 for more professional support :)

Comment: yes using it. Is there any better short alternative without major changes to code